# Assigning seats in Data Structure

Tags: java, list, data-structures, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I need to store a list of seats (representing a coach/plane etc) of n rows and m columns. I also need the ability to assign the seat to an object.

I was thinking a map could be perfect for this if I could use some form of data structure such similar to a Tuple for the key.

e.g.

```
map = { (0,0): null,
        (0,1): Person1Object,
        (0,2): Person2Object,
        ...
        (n,m): PersonNObject
      }
```

Where (0,0) would identify the row and column of seat. Then null would identify a seat isn't taken.

But i'm not sure if this method is even possible as maps I've seen usually use a String as the key. I've also considered using multidimensional arrays and lists for the problem.

Can anyone advise on the best method for storing this collection of data?

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine a `PersonObject[][]` would be easiest. Wrap it in some sort of controller class so you don't have to worry about the structure anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a two dimensional array of `PersonObject` to do this, the usage would be:

```
final PersonObject[][] seats = new PersonObject[x][y];
//set a person
seats[a][b] = myPerson
//get a person
final PersonObject myPerson = seats[a][b];
```

If the size of the data is unknown you can use `List`s rather than arrays:

```
final List<List<PersonObject>> seats = new ArrayList<List<PersonObject>>();
//set a person
List<PersonObject> list = seats.get(a);
if(list == null) {
  list = new ArrayList<PersonObject>();
  seats.add(a, list);
}
list.add(b, myPerson);
//get a person
final PersonObject myPerson = seats.get(a).get(b);
```

Note the second approach is much more prone to error as you need to put the people into the rows in order otherwise `seats.add(a, list)` will cause an error. And if people aren't put into the columns in order `list.add(b, myPerson)` will cause an error.

To get around this you could use the datastructure you suggest, this would look like

```
final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PersonObject>> seats = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, PersonObject>>();
//set a person
Map<Integer, PersonObject> map = seats.get(a);
if(map == null) {
  map = new HashMap<Integer, PersonObject>();
  seats.put(a, map);
}
map.put(b, myPerson);
//get a person
myPerson.get(a).get(b);
```

This get method will throw a `NullPointerException` if there is no row `a`. This can avoided by extending the `HashMap` and overriding the `put` method:

```
final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PersonObject>> seats = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, PersonObject>>(){
  @Override
  public  Map<Integer, PersonObject> get(Object key) {
     Map<Integer, PersonObject> map = super.get(key);
     if(map == null) {
        map = new HashMap<Integer, PersonObject>();
        put((Integer)key, map);
     }
     return map;
  }
};
//set a person    
map.seats.get(a).put(b, myPerson);
//get a person
myPerson.get(a).get(b);
```

Because the outer `Map` now autocreates the inner maps there will be no errors. This structure works much better with sparse data.

If you allowed to look at 3rd party libraries, google guava has the exact thing that you need, a [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) which is essentially a wrapper around the final datastructure.

Another alternative would be to use a `Map<Point, PersonObject>` as the `Point` class already exists an represents a point in two dimensional space.

```
final Map<Point, PersonObject> seats = new HashMap<Point, PersonObject>();
//set a person  
seats.put(new Point(a,b), myPerson);
//get a person
myPerson = seats.get(new Point(a,b));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n` and `m` are known, why don't you use an array instead?

```
PersonObject[][] seats = new PersonObject[n][m];
```

---

The data structure you describe is possible. It would be

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, PersonObject>> seats = ...
```

But it does not seem to suit your needs as it will introduce a lot of memory overhead you do not need and it is also not very convenient to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a 2 dimensional array of `PersonObjects` and use indexes as a indication of the row and column number

example :

```
PersonObject seatMatrix = new PersonObject[100][100];
```

to indicate that the row 0, column 1 is taken(occupied) do this:

```
seatMatrix[0][1] = new PersonObject();
```

To check if a particular(ex: row 1 column 1) seat is taken , you can do this:

```
if(seatMatrix[1][1] != null)
{
     //this seat is taken
}
else
{
     // this seat is not taken!
}
```